# How do I use javascript in Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am creating an Acrobat file with multiple pages. Each page has a map and a list of names down the side. Each name is a button and I have JavaScript entered for each, so that when you hover the mouse over the button, the corresponding name shows up at it's location on the map (via a text field), and then when you move your cursor away from the button, the text field disappears.

Here is the code I have for `MouseEnter`:

```js
this.getField("Kyle Deal").display = display.visible;
```

Here is the code I have for `MouseExit`:

```js
this.getField("Kyle Deal").display = display.hidden;
```

It works great if you stay on one page, but my problem is, is that when you hover the mouse over the button and the name appears and you move to a new page, and then come back, the text field is still there because the `MouseExit` never actually triggered when you were on the page the first time, no matter where your cursor is now. This happens way more often than it sounds like it might, pretty much every time someone uses this document at all.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can go about resolving this issue whether it be by a bit of JavaScript that clears all functions when you move to a new page, or maybe I can edit the `MouseEnter` function to go away after a certain period of time, or some other method inside Acrobat's settings?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would need some field renaming (to make things easier). You would set all relevant fields to hidden when leaving the page.

Now with hierarchical field names, where the fields on page 2, for example, would have a name "`p2.xxx`", your command in the pageOut event would be

```
this.getField("p2").display = display.hidden ;
```

and that would do it.

Otherwise, you would have to hide field by field in the pageOut event.